# Why can not two subdomains point to the same CNAME?

Tags: dns, amazon-elb

I have an Amazon Elastic Load Balancer (ELB) which is available via a CNAME.

The Loadbalancer forwards it's traffic to an HAProxy instance, which splits the traffic and redirects it do different services.

Given I own the domain `mydomain.com` and want traffic of two subdomains hit the same loadbalancer, I setup both subdomains with my domain registry as CNAME record.

`www.mydomain.com` -> CNAME record points to ELB
`board.mydomain.com` -> CNAME record points to same ELB

As soon as I set `board.mydomain.com` things start to fail. So why can not two subdomains point to the same CNAME?

Comment: How exactly does it fail?

Comment: As soon as I add the CNAME record for the second subdomain, the first one - set before - becomes unavailable. I can not imagine, why this should happen. Guess it's a problem at my domain registry.

Comment: Your setup is quite common and should work. First test DNS resolution using some 3rd party tool, like https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/

Comment: Thats was my expectation too as also several A records can point to the same IP. I have no explanation, so I guess I will have to contact the domain registry support. Thx for your comments on the issue.

Comment: There's another piece of this puzzle that you are overlooking or are not aware of.  An infinite number of DNS CNAME entries could point to an ELB or any other target, and impact nothing.  You have not really explained what you mean when you say the first one "becomes unavailable."